# Как разделить строку через split по двум разделителям " " и "|". JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Пробовал так,

```
    let hashtags = el.value.split('/| |\s|/');
```

не вышло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно или экранировать |, или использовать его в классе символов. И не заключать регулярное выражение в кавычки)

```js
console.log('a b|c'.split(/\||\s/));

console.log('a b|c'.split(/[|\s]/));
```